# Is it possible to write a large chunk of data to localStorage or the DOM without blocking things like animated gifs?

Tags: javascript, performance

When I write apps using PhoneGap and download a fairly large chunk of data to store for offline use (~4kb), I've noticed that if there's an animated gif visible (e.g. the jQueryMobile loading gif) then it stops animating while the data is being written to LocalStorage. (Perhaps this case is more about the sheer number of writes to LocalStorage and less about the combined size of the records?)

The same is true for adding large chunks of HTML to the DOM. If I render a HandlebarsJS template that's around 100 `<li>`'s or something and then inject it into the DOM (as would seem to be the best practice), page scrolling and animated gifs just stop functioning until the append is complete.

From the user's perspective, it looks as if the app has locked up for several seconds (in a sense it has...) and there is temptation to kill it; even though it's still working.

Is there something I can do to prevent this behavior? I'd even be willing to sacrifice a little bit of real-performance, as it would improve perceived-performance...

Comment: You shouldn't be loading hundreds of thousands of `<li>` elements. No one can absorb that much information at one time, so don't present it to them.

Comment: Maybe I didn't give enough thought to that sentence. In general I don't present them with that much information, but certainly hundreds. Say you're rendering the attendee list for an event. I'll break it up into groups split by certain chunks of the alphabet -- but regardless, even with only a hundred or two items I've seen the gif-freezing issue.

Comment: @zzzzBov just noticed you said "hundreds of thousands" -- not sure if you misread what I wrote "hundreds OR thousands" (moot anyway because it's rarely over 100) or if you typo'd when you wrote "of".

Comment: I totally misread it as "hundreds of thousands" instead of "hundreds or thousands". The advice still stands, but is less relevant to this question if it's rarely over 100.

Answer (score 0):

Chunk it up. Do some testing to see how much you can write in one go without impacting animation on a "regular" pc and limit your writes to that amount. Simply append multiple times or in the case of LocalStorage write to consecutive keys.

Comment: "in the case of LocalStorage write to consecutive keys." -- Already doing this. That's the issue. It's essentially a loop over the returned records that does a `localStorage.setItem(key, value)`

Comment: You have to relinquish control between writes. Do a setTimeout(myWritingFunc, 0) until you're done writing. JavaScript is single-threaded.